# Express app using MongoDB not working on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I'm sorry for the vagueness in advance, but I have NO clue what information to post here.

I've been developing my own blog, using Heroku to deploy it and MongoDB as my database. When I'm running the website locally, everything works perfectly. Composing blogs, publishing them, and scrolling through them. When I go to the webapp deployed on Heroku however, I can load up the empty homepage or the compose page. But as soon as I go to the blogpage or I want to publish a post it crashes.

These actions both interact with MongoDB, so I can at least guess the problem occurs when I'm connecting with Mongo. The deployed webapp is found [here](https://coded-by-tom.herokuapp.com/).

When trying to visit the blog page with displays all posts, I get a lot of these in the Heroku console until it crashes after 30 seconds:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blog"
```

When I'm trying to publish a new post I get this:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/compose"
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is how I'm connecting using Mongoose (MYUSERNAME and MYPASSWORD is only in the example, in the real project they are actually there of course):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Server started listening to port " + port);
});
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@coded-by-tom-jk5zo.mongodb.net/blogDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
let blogDB = mongoose.connection;
blogDB.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

blogDB.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Connection to database succesfull.");
});

app.get("/blog", (req, res) => {
  Post.find({}, async (err, posts) => {
    await res.render("blog", {
      posts: posts.reverse()
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, although I'm not sure why this is the answer. To upload an app to Heroku you have to add the language and the version of the language you're using in the packages.json file. In the course I was watching, it was added just before "dependencies". I altered it to be specified at the end of the file, and this seems to have done the trick. So for anyone having problems with deploying their apps to Heroku, you might try this as this is a solution that I haven't found yet on StackOverflow.